# How to remove <table> structure with python from this case?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

How to remove  "table" from HTML using python?

I had case like this:

```
paragraph = '''
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem molestiae consequuntur officiis corporis sint.<br /><br />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    text title
</td>
<td>
    text title 2
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p> lorem ipsum</p>
'''
```

how to remove content with table structure as above using python?
And I want the output produced to be as follows:

```
paragraph = '''
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem molestiae consequuntur officiis corporis sint.<br /><br />
<p> lorem ipsum</p>
'''
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: will it always start with <table> and end with </table> and can you use regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complicated to use *regex*, a stupid way I suggested:

```
def remove_table(s):
    left_index = s.find('<table>')
    if -1 == left_index:
        return s
    right_index = s.find('</table>', left_index)
    return s[:left_index] + remove_table(s[right_index + 8:])
```

There may be some blank lines inside the result.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i try your source code is working. your answer according to my case.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation) especially [`PageElement.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)

```
In [16]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [17]: soup = BeautifulSoup("""<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem molestiae consequuntur officiis corporis sint.<br /><br />
   ....: <table>
   ....: <tr>
   ....: <td>
   ....:     text title or some
   ....: </td>
   ....: </tr>
   ....: </table>
   ....: <p> lorem ipsum</p>""")

In [18]: _ = soup.table.extract()

In [19]: soup
Out[19]: 
<html><body><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem molestiae consequuntur officiis corporis sint.<br/><br/>
</p>
<p> lorem ipsum</p></body></html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a solution without using a module.
perhaps with regex or other methods.
but your answers will be my capacity for alternatives.

Comment: @AriPrihantoro you don't want to use `regex` why? because it will [explode your head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I look for another method, instead of using the module as BeautifulSoup or another.
I prefer to use methods such as regex.
maybe you misunderstood my point.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this basic string formatting

```
paragraph = paragraph[:paragraph.find('<table>')] +     # Find the starting letter of '<table>'
            paragraph[paragraph.find('</table>')+       # Find the starting letter of </table>
            (len('<\table>')+1):]                       # Add 1 because length starts from zero

print(paragraph)
```

Even this work for basic text extraction

Comment: yea, i will ask like this.

Comment: Would you have a lot of <table>s?

Comment: not the number of his table, if from me what if the number of columns of the table more than 1.